# Get TextField->text() from slot Blackberry 10

Tags: c++, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm a complete beginner in Blackberry 10 development. I'm developing an app that should take user input from a text box and search if there is an occurrence of the word in a text file. I'm using the triggered() signal of ActionItem to invoke the search. However, when I try to fetch the user input from within the slot it always returns an empty string ''. What mistake I'm I making.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

main.qml

```
TextField {
        objectName: "anagram"
        hintText: "Enter anagram to search"
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

        input {
            submitKey: SubmitKey.Done

        }            
}
```

application.cpp

```
ActionItem *main = root->findChild<ActionItem*>("search");
bool res1 = QObject::connect(main, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onSearch()));


void ApplicationUI::onSearch()
{
    qDebug() << "slot activated";
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
    Application::instance()->setScene(root);
    TextField* query = root->findChild<TextField*>("anagram");
    //THE STRING BELOW ALWAYS RETURNS ''
    QString search = query->text();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

When the slot `onSearch` is invoked you are effectively creating an additional UI, unrelated to the one that actually emitted the signal.

Since there's no default setting for the *text* property of `anagram`, what you have concluded is correct; it will always yield an empty string since the field will always be freshly created.

---

#### Solution

You will need to use the `root` associated with the current UI (that the user has inputted data to), instead of creating a new one.

Assuming that you have declared `root` as a data-member of *ApplicationUI*, the below would do what you'd expect (and want).

```
void ApplicationUI::onSearch()
{
    qDebug() << "slot activated";
    TextField* query = root->findChild<TextField*>("anagram");
    QString search = query->text();
    // ... 
}
```

---

<sub>**Alternative solution**</sub>

You could also access the current loaded scene (the equivalent of `root` in your snippet) by calling `scene()` on the pointer-to `AbstractPane` returned by `Application::instance ()`:

```
AbstractPane *   current_scene = Application::instance ()->scene ();
QString search = current_scene->findChild<TextField*> ("anagram")->text ();
```

Comment: How do you declare root as a data-member of ApplicationUI?

Comment: @Wedava that's beyond the scope of the question, though you should me familiar with members of a class when writing C++. However, I just added an alternative solution that would work *"as is"*.

Comment: I had tried the standard C++ way but it was not working. The alternative solution works perfect though. Thank you very much @Filip.